# Cannot watch any event on Ropsten

Tags: truffle, events, ropsten

I'm not able to watch and log event sent by smart contract using the Ropsten test network.
The same code works on local test network.

**Contract Event code**:

```
event CreateOptionEvent(address indexed _who, uint256 indexed _date, uint256 indexed _id);

function createOption( ...PARAMS HERE... ){

    [...]

    emit CreateOptionEvent(msg.sender, now, optionId);
}
```

**Web app event code**:

```
createEvent = myContractInstance.CreateOptionEvent({ fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' })
createEvent.watch((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return;
    }
    console.log(result.args._id)
})
```

After I correctly create an option (`transaction success on metamask`) nothing is logged.

What should I try to do?

```
-> % truffle version 
Truffle v4.1.11 (core: 4.1.11) 
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to events as shown in [Web3 documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events). Also you would need to create new instance with websocket provider for it (for example *wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws*) as MetaMask doesn't support websockets i believe.

Comment: Can you please link a tutorial or explain how to create a websocket provider.

Anyway on custom RPC testnet i'm able to log event. Only on ropsten i can't do it.

Thank you

Comment: Everything is in Web3 documentation http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#setprovider . You can use Infura ws on both testnets and on main-net too.